# 3 equations 4 unknowns.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to know what does this system describes please: 
$x+3t=2$

$y+t=-1$

$z+2t=1 $

Now subtracting equation (1) from (2) and (3) i.e (1)-(2)-(3) leads to
$x-y-z=2$ hence the set of points of the system describes a plane knowing that this system has infinite of solutions. Am i right doing so? Is there anyway to determine what does the system describes by getting the bases of the set of points obtained by the system?(found it hard since it's not homogenous)

Comment: I would say - parametric equations of the line passing through the point (2, -1,1) with direction vector $ \ vec {v} (3,1,2) $ in the Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: Let $t$ stand for time and let $(x,y,x)=(2,-1,1)+t(3,1,2)$ be the spot where some object is at time $t$. It took off at $(2,-1,1)$.

Comment: Have you studied linear systems of equations? If you put this question into an augmented matrix form and perform Gaussian elimination, you will see that you have 1 free variable, so you are going to get a straight line. Others have answered the question with the specifics of this line.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$x=2-3t, y=-1-t, z=1-2t,$$ or $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\1\end{matrix}\right)+t\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\-1\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$$ which is the equation of a straight line.

The equation of the plane you have found is one of infinitely many which contain this line